How can I use a type for getting the value by passing a key?
I have below TypeScript type:
export type MHStatus = {
    AVAILABLE: "AVAILABLE"
    IN_PROGRESS: "IN_PROGRESS"
    UNAVAILABLE: "UNAVAILABLE"
}

Now, I have one function which does below part:
    const status = isTrue? MHStatus['AVAILABLE'] : MHStatus['UNAVAILABLE'] 
    
    const formatOnj = await formatobjTOAdd(getterSetter, id, status)

Now I have below function:
export const formatobjTOAdd = (getterSetter: GetterSetter, requestId?: string, status?: MHStatus) => { 


}

Here it throws an error says type cannot be used. Can anyone help me here?

Why is that a type?! Seems like you actually want an enum or even just a plain object, so it actually has a value at runtime.

In short: TypeScript can't run in a browser (yet). It must be compiled to JavaScript. JavaScript doesn't have types. So MHStatus is deleted when compiled to JavaScript. If you actually need to use a value in your code, then it can't be a type.

The reason you get this error is that you are trying to use a type as a value, which doesn't work because types do not exist at runtime.
If you want to keep the code mostly the same you can turn MHStatus into an enum like this:
enum MHStatus {
    AVAILABLE = "AVAILABLE",
    IN_PROGRESS = "IN_PROGRESS",
    UNAVAILABLE = "UNAVAILABLE"
}

Full working example (with missing details added):
enum MHStatus {
    AVAILABLE = "AVAILABLE",
    IN_PROGRESS = "IN_PROGRESS",
    UNAVAILABLE = "UNAVAILABLE"
}

type GetterSetter = 'get' | 'set';
const isTrue: boolean = true;
const getterSetter = 'get';
const id = 'requestId';

const formatobjTOAdd = (getterSetter: GetterSetter, requestId?: string, status?: MHStatus) => 
{ 
    
}

 const myStatus = isTrue? MHStatus['AVAILABLE'] : MHStatus['UNAVAILABLE'] 
const formatOnj = formatobjTOAdd(getterSetter, id, myStatus)

Playground
